# 2d array list comprehension with an index lookup

Tags: python, arrays

I have a simple 2d array like so:

```
arr = [[2,1,0],[0,2,1]]
```

Now I am trying to replace the values inside the 2d array with values from a list by using the values inside the array as the index of the list. For example my list looks like this:

```
list = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fox']
```

I am trying to get a result like this:

```
[['Fox','Dog','Cat'],['Cat','Fox','Dog']]
```

I trying to figure out how to do this efficiently using list comprehensions, however I can't find a way that seems works.

I thought this should work:

```
[list[x] for x in y for y in arr ]
```

However, it tells me `NameError: name 'y' is not defined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
arr = [[2,1,0],[0,2,1]]

lst = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fox']

result = [[lst[i] for i in sublist] for sublist in arr]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['Fox', 'Dog', 'Cat'], ['Cat', 'Fox', 'Dog']]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for! I'll accept once SO lets me :)